# Is credit card signup bonus taxable?

Tags: united-states, taxes, credit-card, reward-program

If a credit card company offers you $500 for making $1500 in purchases within the first 3 months, is that taxable income?

Comment: Nope. Signup bonuses from banks are though.

Comment: similar question to [Are credit card rewards taxable?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/854/are-credit-card-rewards-taxable) .

Answer (score 5):

No. If the reward is contingent on spending, then it is not considered taxable income. This is true of cash-back, points, and sign-up bonuses that are based on spending (Spend $x in first x months).

Edit: Seeking a better IRS source, the below has to do with personal use of rewards from business spending, but a more specific source may not exist, there are indeed unwritten tax rules that have been formed based on vaguely related written rules.

[IRS Bulletin No. 2002–10](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-irbs/irb02-10.pdf) is referenced as the basis for this rule, but it is specifically regarding personal use of frequent flier miles earned through business travel.